# trying to make dynamic NSString texts into bold text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to iOS Development..I cannot get my strings to get BOLD.

Thanks in advance!
Here's my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *sentence = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@", self.name, self.adjective, self.noun, self.verb]];

NSMutableAttributedString *finalSentence = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:sentence];

NSRange nameRange = NSMakeRange(0, self.name.length);
NSRange adjectiveRange = NSMakeRange(self.name.length, self.adjective.length);
NSRange nounRange = NSMakeRange((self.adjective.length + self.name.length), self.noun.length);
NSRange verbRange = NSMakeRange((self.adjective.length + self.name.length + self.noun.length), self.verb.length);

[finalSentence beginEditing];

[finalSentence addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17.0] range:nameRange];
[finalSentence addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17.0] range:adjectiveRange];
[finalSentence addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0] range:nounRange];
[finalSentence addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0] range:verbRange];

[finalSentence endEditing];

NSString *completeSentence = [finalSentence string];

self.resultTextView.text = completeSentence;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's not an accident that there's a separate `NSAttributedString` class. The `completeSentence`, that you retrieve using your attributed string's `string` property, is a plain `NSString`, does not contain formatting info (because it cannot).

You have to assign the attributed string object itself to the `attributedText` property of your text view.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the plain text version of your attributed text (`[finalSentence string]`) to the plain text property of your `UITextView`.

You should set the attributed text directly to the `attributedText` property of the `UITextView` -

```
self.resultTextView.attributedText=finalSentence
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call

```
self.resultTextView.attributedText = finalSentence;
```

Here is code that you need

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *sentence = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@", self.name, self.adjective, self.noun, self.verb]];

    NSMutableAttributedString *finalSentence = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:sentence];

    NSRange nameRange = NSMakeRange(0, self.name.length);
    NSRange adjectiveRange = NSMakeRange(self.name.length, self.adjective.length);
    NSRange nounRange = NSMakeRange((self.adjective.length + self.name.length), self.noun.length);
    NSRange verbRange = NSMakeRange((self.adjective.length + self.name.length + self.noun.length), self.verb.length);

    [finalSentence beginEditing];

    [finalSentence addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17.0] range:nameRange];
    [finalSentence addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17.0] range:adjectiveRange];
    [finalSentence addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0] range:nounRange];
    [finalSentence addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0] range:verbRange];

    [finalSentence endEditing];
    self.resultTextView.attributedText = finalSentence;
}
```